# Rails/Ruby: uploading a binary File and writing it with a File-Object

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, file-upload, binary

I need to upload Word and Excel files on my site.

I create a upload form, upload the file and save it like this:

```
f = File.new("public/files/#{user.id.to_s}/filename", "w+")
f.write params[:file].read
f.close
```

Word and Excel files must be saved as binary data.

Sadly the Filemode "b" is only for windows and I'm under linux.

What to do?

Yours,

Joern

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Binary file mode "b" may appear with any of the key letters (r, r+, w, w+, a, a+) so you can do it like this `f = File.new("public/files/#{user.id.to_s}/filename", "w+b")`.

And the "b" mode is not only for windows. Ruby documentation says that *"Binary file mode (may appear with any of the key letters r, r+, w, w+, a, a+. Suppresses EOL <-> CRLF conversion on Windows. And sets external encoding to ASCII-8BIT unless explicitly specified."* and says nothing about "b" being just for windows. It just tells that it works different on windows/linux with line endings. So you can use "w+b" mode on linux and windows.